# DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn - If checkBox checked issue

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I have this code down below which should show messageBox when the checkbox in checkbox column is checked. It is test for me that I know that the row was really selected.

If this would work I'm going to save SelectedRows into DB. So maybe its helpful to know when building this code. As I'm begginer I wanted to ask you guys why MessageBox doesnt apper when I check checkBox? 
Thanks so much in advance.

```
  DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
  dtg_ksluzby.Columns.Add(chk);
  dtg_ksluzby.Columns[3].Width = 20;

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg_ksluzby.Rows)
  {
      // number 3 represents the 4th column of dgv
      DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk1 = row.Cells[3] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell; 
      if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk1.Value) == true)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("this cell checked");
      }
      else
      {
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is this inside the checkbox checked event?

Comment: In the code shown, you have only added the column and it
 would be in unchecked state, so looping it won't find any records which has the Checked state true, you will have to check this in a specific event like (hoping winform) like `CellValueChanged` or `CellValidating`

Comment: Well, no. I didn't know exactly where to put it so I put it right after commend which I creates that column. Where should I find checkbox checked event please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will never hit the message box code - you've created the control, added it to the table, then immediately checked them for their values, which will be not set.

You need to have an event handler that catches changed values in the datagridview:

```
private void dtg_ksluzby_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
                                          DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Check through the cells here (or use event args to get data)
}
```

Comment: You will also most likely need to assign this handler to the DataGridView - you can do this through the properties of it in design view for ease. Just set the 'CellValueChanged' (in Events) to the name of the handler (dtg_ksluzby_CellValueChanged)

Comment: i did that. Would you please solve out that If I check two or more columns that checkbox wouldnt appear 3 times?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry i confused messagebox and checkbox. - Would you please solve out that if I check two or more columns that MessageBox wouldnt appear 3 times?

Comment: CellValueChanged is fired from a few events, so all of them may not be the checkbox changing - use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs object to find out what happened and filter it appropriately